# Recursive search grep

Tags: linux, grep, hdfs

I'm trying to search through HDFS for parquet files and list them out. I'm using this, which works great. It looks through all of the subdirectories in `/sources.works_dbo` and gives me all the parquet files:

```
 hdfs dfs -ls -R /sources/works_dbo | grep ".*\.parquet$"
```

However; I just want to return the first file it encounters per subdirectory, so that each subdirectory only appears on a single line in my output. Say I had this:

```
sources/works_dbo/test1/file1.parquet
sources/works_dbo/test1/file2.parquet
sources/works_dbo/test2/file3.parquet
```

When I run my command I expect the output to look like this:

```
sources/works_dbo/test1/file1.parquet
sources/works_dbo/test2/file3.parquet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sort -u` (unique) with `/` as the delimiter and using the first three fields as key. The `-s` option ("stable") makes sure that the file retained is the first one encountered for each subdirectory.

For this input

```
sources/works_dbo/test1/file1.parquet
sources/works_dbo/test1/file2.parquet
sources/works_dbo/test2/file3.parquet
```

the result is

```
$ sort -s -t '/' -k 1,3 -u infile
sources/works_dbo/test1/file1.parquet
sources/works_dbo/test2/file3.parquet
```

Comment: This is really elegant.

Answer (score 2):

```
... | awk '!seen[gensub(/[^/]+$/,"",1)]++' file
sources/works_dbo/test1/file1.parquet
sources/works_dbo/test2/file3.parquet
```

The above uses GNU awk for gensub(), with other awks you'd use a variable and sub():

```
awk '{path=$0; sub(/[^/]+$/,"",path)} !seen[path]++'
```

It will work for any mixture of any length of paths.

Answer (score 1):

If the subdirectories are of variable length, this `awk` solution may come in handy:

```
 hdfs dfs -ls -R /sources/works_dbo | awk '
     BEGIN{FS="/"; OFS="/";} 
     {file=$NF;                   // file name is always the last field
      $NF=""; folder=$0;          // chomp off the last field to cache folder
      if (!(folder in seen_dirs)) // cache the first file per folder
          seen_dirs[folder]=file;
     }
     END{
      for (f in seen_dirs)        // after we've processed all rows, print our cache
          print f,seen_dirs[f];
     }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl:

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R /sources/works_dbo | grep '.*\.parquet$' | \
  perl -MFile::Basename -nle 'print unless $h{ dirname($_) }++'
```

In the *perl* command above:

- `-M` loads [`File::Basename`](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Basename) module;
- `-n` causes Perl to apply the expression passed via `-e` for each input line;
- `-l` preserves the line terminator;
- `$_` is the default variable keeping the currently read line;
- `dirname($_)` returns the directory part for the path specified by `$_`;
- `$h` is a hash where keys are directory names, and values are integers 0, 1, 2 etc;
- the line is printed to the standard output, unless the directory name is seen in the previous iterations, i.e. the hash value `$h{ dirname($_) }` is non-zero.

---

By the way, instead of piping the result of `hdfs dfs -ls -R` via `grep`, you can use the [`find`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#find) command:

```
hdfs dfs -find /sources/works_dbo -name '*.parquet'
```